# "insert or update" для строки таблицы в SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, plsql-developer

Нужно проапдейтить значение в строке

```
update my_table set status = 4, complete_date = sysdate
    where a = 2 and b = 5 and c = 5
```

Но если такая строка не нашлась, то выполнить что-то вроде

```
insert into my_table status, complete_date, a, b, c 
    values 4, sysdate, null, null, null
```

По идее, можно это выполнить через select в переменную (например счетчик) и если он равен нулю - выполняем insert, иначе update. Но как это выполнить через merge?

Comment: А "такая запись не нашлась" - это какая ? приведите условия первичного ключа для примера, иначе вы не поймете в ответе где там писать эти условия ...

Comment: Если вы знаете, что надо сделать через merge, то почему вы не попытались этого сделаеть? Синтакс не намного сложней, чем предложенные два выражения в вопросе.

Comment: @Mike пример `where a = 2 and b = 5 and c = 5`

Comment: @0xdb - в этом и суть вопроса. Никогда не сталкивался с такой задачей и как-то тяжело заходит понимание синтаксиса в мануале. Надеюсь, что с ответом станет понятнее и использую уже в своей "боевой" задаче.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
merge into my_table m
using (select
        4 status,
        sysdate complete_date,
        2 a, 
        5 b, 
        5 c
       from dual
       ) v on (m.a = v.a AND m.b = v.b AND m.c = v.c)
when matched then
    update set my_table.status = v.status, complete_date = v.complete_date
when not matched then
    insert (status, complete_date, a, b, c)
    values(v.status, v.complete_date v.a, v.b, v.c);
```

PS этот код не тестировался и может содержать ошибки...

Comment: Сделал так (в боевом виде по аналогии, конечно). Вроде компилится, посмотрим как накатится в обнове :D
`merge into my_table t
    using (select
        2 a, 5 b, 5 c
        from dual
        ) v on (t.a=v.a and t.b=v.b and t.c=v.c)
    when matched then
        update set status = 4, complete_date = sysdate
    when not matched then
        insert (status, complete_date, a, b, c)
            values(4, sysdate, v.a, v.b, v.c);`

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов, я предпочитаю вариант, в котором все константы находятся в одном месте -  в виртуальной таблице `v`

Comment: да, я уже исправил к момент вашего коммента. А пока писал первый комментарий вы вставили значения переменных в ответ :) Разница только в том, что я после using не выбираю статус и дату из дуала т.к. если уже всё есть в таблице, то и update не нужен. Спасибо, очень помогло!